# Error showing while updating database with Identity Column

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

Please help me... i am trying to update my database from VB.net. It shows error. My code is given below....

```
Try
            getConnect()

            Dim strSQL As String
            strSQL = " UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET [DEP_ID]=@DEP_ID,[DEPART]=@DEPART,    [DEP_DSCRPTN]=@DEP_DSCRPTN WHERE [DEP_ID] = @DEP_ID"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, Conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_ID", CInt(Me.DEPID.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPART", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =     CMBDEPT.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_DSCRPTN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =     TXTDESC.Text
            Conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Update Complete!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
        Finally
            Conn.Close()
            BTNCLEAR.PerformClick()
        End Try
```

And the error is:

> ERROR: Cannot update identity column 'DEP_ID'

Comment: The error message is clear, remove the Set DEP_ID = @DEP_ID part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear, remove the Set DEP_ID = @DEP_ID part.

```
Try
    getConnect()

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET [DEPART]=@DEPART," + 
             "[DEP_DSCRPTN]=@DEP_DSCRPTN WHERE [DEP_ID] = @DEP_ID"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, Conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_ID", CInt(Me.DEPID.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPART", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =     CMBDEPT.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEP_DSCRPTN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =     TXTDESC.Text
    Conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Update Complete!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ERROR: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
Finally
    Conn.Close()
    BTNCLEAR.PerformClick()
End Try
```

If you find yourself in need to change an Identity column then I think you need to analyze better your database schema.

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` has no effect on Updates and it is clear from the query that they don't need to update it anyway. The `SET` would be to the same value as the column already has.

Comment: Thnx Steave and Martin Smith.. Thank you so much... Itz working properly..... Thnx for your fast response.... :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `[DEP_ID]=@DEP_ID,` from the `SET`. It makes no sense to try and set it to the value already ensured by the `WHERE` anyway so it is clearly redundant and it is not permitted to update `IDENTITY` columns.

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT
SET    [DEPART] = @DEPART,
       [DEP_DSCRPTN] = @DEP_DSCRPTN
WHERE  [DEP_ID] = @DEP_ID
```